# Perl regex matching - Using * on both sides of the equation

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write a script that accepts a string input, and a file input.

The string input would look like:

```
input_range*_blah
```

The file would contain lines like so

```
*_blah
input*_*ah
blah1
blah2
blah3
```

I want the script to produce matches for the first and second lines in this particular example.

I am unable to figure out the syntax for this, would someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you want to search for a literal * char?  If so, just escape it:  \\*

Comment: It's hard to understand why this pattern is supposed to match either the first or the second line. Is the idea that each line in the file represents a pattern, and the program should print out every pattern that matches the string input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, your file consists of a list of patterns, and you want to print out each of the patterns that matches your input string.  So you would print `*_blah` and `input*_*ah` because both of those patterns match `input_range*_blah`, but not `blah1` or the following patterns, because they don't match the input string.

In that case, I don't think you need any special handling of the asterisks.  In the target string, an asterisk is just another character -- it's not interpreted any special way.  This code should do it:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::Glob qw/match_glob/;

my $input_string = $ARGV[0];
shift;

while (defined (my $pattern = <>)) {
    chomp $pattern;
    print $pattern, "\n" if (match_glob($pattern, $input_string));
}
```

Demo: using a file `glob.dat` containing your example strings:

```
$ perl glob.pl 'input_range*_blah' glob.dat
*_blah
input*_*ah
```

Comment: Just curious though, if you had to do this without the use of Glob, would it be possible?

Comment: If you write the patterns in the file to be actual regular expressions, then instead of `match_glob($pattern, $input_string)` you could use `$input_string =~ /^$pattern$/`. The example patterns you described here are not regular expressions but what are known in Unix as "filename glob patterns" to be a regular expression, you would replace `*` with `.*` in the pattern.

Comment: I tried converting '*'s into '.*'s when I read the file, line by line, and then tried what you suggested, But it doesn't seem to work.

    while (<INPUTFILE>) {
      my ($line) = $_;
      chomp ($line);
      chomp ($sknobs_name); 
      # Convert Unix regex to Perl regex
      my $line_orig = $line; 
      $sknobs_name =~ s/\*/.*/g;
      $line        =~ s/\*/.*/g;
      $sknobs_name =~ s/\+//g;
      $line        =~ s/\+//g;
      print "DEBUG: Line: $line Sknobs:  $sknobs_name\n";
      if ($sknobs_name =~ m/^$line$/) {
        print "$line_orig\n";
      }
      }

Comment: If `$sknobs_name` is the "input string" that you have gotten from the command line, then don't make any changes to it at all. Just leave it exactly as it was passed to the program. For `$line`, try just this: `$line =~ s/[.+\[\]()]/\\$1/g; $line =~ s/\?/./g; $line =~ s/\*/.*/g;` If your patterns have other regular expression characters in them then you will have to account for those as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `*` characters in your match. Try using this regex:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $input, '<', 'in.txt' or die "$!";

my $match = '(.*\*.*)'; 

while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    print "$_\n" if /$match/;
}
```

Which will declare a variable as a match for anything before or after a literal `*` and, reading your input file line by line, print out those lines that match it

Comment: I don't think this really answers the problem. What is the string input to this file that the OP mentioned? How would it match `*_blah` or `input*_*ah` in the file input?

Comment: The issue is that the string input ($match in your example above) is also fed in as an input to the script. Are you suggesting I manipulate the input before trying to do the regex match?

Comment: @AdityaKV - I'm not sure I know what you mean. Do you want to read in from the STDIN?

Comment: I use GetOptions () to read command line inputs into the script